# Can't make PDF through pdflatex on Texnicle (Mac)

Tags: errors, compiling, mac, texnicle

I get this message, but there is no updated PDF:

> `/Users/Arnstein/Library/Application
>   Support/TeXnicle/engines/pdflatex.engine: line 50:
>   /usr/texbin/pdflatex: is a directory
>   *** pdflatex.engine has completed.`

What to do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a copy of the pdfLaTeX engine (in the Preferences in TeXnicle under Typesetting/Engines) then point it at the correct place where your `pdflatex` binary is. To find out where it is, you could try opening a terminal and doing

```
$ which pdflatex
```

TeXnicle is configured out of the box to work with a standard MacTeX installation. If you have an alternative installation, you'll need to configure the engines yourself. Feel free to contact `support at bobsoft-mac.de` to get further help.